# Matching between two ! in a file in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a file where every block is separated by `!`s. i.e

```
!
 vserver XXXX
 virtual XX.xx.XX.XX tcp 389
 owner LDAP
 serverfarm XXX
 idle 5
 persistent rebalance
 inservice
!
```

I want to get each section that is contains vserver info.  I am trying to use regex in python, but I am having trouble dealing with the newline char

I tried something like this:

```
pattern = r"!\n vserver \S+\n "
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to tell Python that you're using [multi-line](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE) regular expressions and that [dot characters can match new-lines](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.DOTALL):

```
>>> m = re.search('^!.*^!', text, re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
>>> m.group(0)
'!\n vserver XXXX\n virtual XX.xx.XX.XX tcp 389\n owner LDAP\n serverfarm XXX\n idle 5\n persistent rebalance\n inservice\n!'
```

If you want to get the *name* of the vserver:

```
>>> m = re.search('^!.*vserver\s+(\w+).*^!', text, re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
>>> m.group(0)
'!\n vserver XXXX\n virtual XX.xx.XX.XX tcp 389\n owner LDAP\n serverfarm XXX\n idle 5\n persistent rebalance\n inservice\n!'
>>> m.group(1)
'XXXX'
```

Comment: you don't need to enable multiline mode in order for this to work.

Comment: @MK.: You do if you only want to match the exclamation marks at the beginning of a line.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
stri = " the output of open(myfilename,'r').read() "

import re
pattern = r"^!\n vserver \S+\n[^!]+^!"
re.findall(pattern,stri,flags=re.M)
```

The regex:

```
^!\n            -> match a solitary '!' on its own line followed by newline
 vserver \S+\n  -> starting with vserver \S+\n
[^!]+           -> match the rest of the block, up to..
^!              -> another solitary '!' on its own line.
```

Depending on what particular information you want to extract the regex can be refined.

For example to extract the text after `vserver`, I can add in capturing brackets:

```
pattern  = r"^!\n vserver (\S+)\n[^!]+^!"
```

Then:

```
re.findall(pattern,stri,flags=re.M) # returns ['XXXX']
```

Comment: N.B: [`str`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) is the name of a built-in class in Python and is therefore a bad choice of variable name.

Comment: ahh, I always get stung by that -- I'll modify my answer. cheers!

Answer (score 1):

This has the advantage of not reading in the whole file at once

```
from itertools import groupby

with open("data.txt") as infile:
    for block in (j for i,j in groupby(t,'!'.__ne__) if i):
        block = list(block)
        if not block[0].startswith("vserver "):
            continue
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
teststr = """
sdafsad
!
 vserver XXXX
 virtual XX.xx.XX.XX tcp 389
 owner LDAP
 serverfarm XXX
 idle 5
 persistent rebalance
 inservice
!
dsfdasfas
"""

import re

m = re.search("!\n[^!]*vserver[^!]*!", teststr)
print m.group(0)
```

Comment: N.B: [`str`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) is the name of a built-in class in Python and is therefore a bad choice of variable name!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a big fan of regexs, how about a list comp?

```
vserver_blocks = [block for block in data.split("!") if "vserver" in block]
```